# what causes :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED and how can it be solved?

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-multidex

How can I solve this error?

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

  > java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Raphael\Desktop\EZYAGRIC\EzyAgric-Android-App-master\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Raphael\Desktop\EZYAGRIC\EzyAgric-Android-App-master\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\127.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [127.jar:com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class]))

I have tried all the similar questions but in vain. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dagger then fix it with following code:

I encountered the exact same error regarding Beta.class and 
resolved it by excluding all occurrences of guava:

```
compile ('com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
```

Comment: This is how i was using dagger                                                                                               // Dagger:
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'

Comment: Let me try and replace it with your suggestion

Comment: I realised that it comes when I add the following in gradle[ implementation(group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-android', version: '1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation(group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-drive', version: 'v3-rev64-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation(group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-sheets', version: 'v4-rev463-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }]

Comment: You can try this as well:
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev64-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }